# Tic Tac Toe--infinite loop--how do I prompt second move?

Tags: javascript

Second day of schoool, we got assigned a tic-tac-toe game.  I'm building it with 9 clickable divs.  Once one is clicked on, the X appears in that div, and the computer then makes his move.  My problem is that I can't properly signal the end of the user turn and beginning of CPU's turn.  I have a counter counting the total moves (moveCount).  My first thought was to set a while loop, so while (moveCount = 0), the user can pick a div and then moveCount will increment to 1, and the loop will end, and then the computer can play.  But it just isn't working that way.  Any help to get me going would be greatly appreciated!

```
    let playerName = prompt("Welcome to my world.  Enter your name so we can start");
alert("Welcome to the Game" + playerName + "!  Pick whatever square you'd like!");

let moveCount = 0;
let userArray = [];
let cpuArray = [];

let topLeft = 0;
let topMiddle = 0
let topRight = 0
let middleLeft = 0
let middleMiddle = 0
let middleRight = 0
let bottomLeft = 0
let bottomMiddle = 0
let bottomRight = 0

while(moveCount === 0){
    $("#top-left").bind("click", function () {
        $('<p>X</p>').appendTo(this)
        moveCount++
        topLeft++
    });

    $("#top-middle").bind("click", function () {
        moveCount++;
        topMiddle++
        $('<p>X</p>').appendTo(this)
    });

    $("#top-right").bind("click", function () {
        moveCount++;
        topRight++
        $('<p>X</p>').appendTo(this)
    });

    $("#middle-left").bind("click", function () {
        moveCount++;
        middleLeft++
        $('<p>X</p>').appendTo(this)
    });
    $("#middle-middle").bind("click", function () {
        moveCount++;
        middleMiddle++
        $('<p>X</p>').appendTo(this)
    });

    $("#middle-right").bind("click", function () {
        moveCount++;
        middleRight++
        $('<p>X</p>').appendTo(this)
    });
    $("#bottom-left").bind("click", function () {
        moveCount++;
        bottomLeft++
        $('<p>X</p>').appendTo(this)
    });

    $("#bottom-middle").bind("click", function () {
        moveCount++;
        bottomMiddle++
        $('<p>X</p>').appendTo(this)
    });

    $("#bottom-right").bind("click", function () {
        moveCount++;
        bottomRight++
        $('<p>X</p>').appendTo(this)
    });

};


//computer turn
if (moveCount === 1){
alert("The computer cannot be defeated.  Click to see his turn.");
if (topLeft === 1 || topRight === 1 || bottomRight === 1 || bottomLeft === 1) {
    $('<p>0</p>').appendTo("#middle-middle")
    moveCount++
    middleMiddle++
};



if (topMiddle === 1 || middleLeft === 1 || middleRight === 1 || bottomMiddle === 1) { };
if (middleMiddle === 1) { };



};
```

Comment: trigger next move when you are incrementing `moveCount`. hint: keep track who moved.

Comment: try using setTimeout instead of using while loop. While loop will never stop and it ll crash the browser. use setTimeout and check if user moved every 200 milliseconds.

Comment: I figured out that second part.  kind of.  I'm making an array to collect the moves of each person so I can try to match that array versus winning arrays.  How do I trigger the next move when I increment?

Comment: @Harry Bomrah, I was hoping the first move would trigger the second move, I'm not waiting for anything.

Comment: well then simply call a function when user clicks and put all the if conditions inside that function.

Comment: Alex, or whoever it was that had an answer below, I loved it, why did you hide your answer man?  That as going to save me so much time!  Please help!

Comment: Please can u make a fiddle. it ll be much easier.

Comment: thanks harry.  https://jsfiddle.net/d3jogu1c/

Comment: hmmm, it stops after it appends the x and doesn't continue after that.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would set up an independent function and a global variable that would handle the turn process. We can call this variable `yourTurn`.

In order to modify the variable to determine who's turn it is, let's make a function called `changeTurns` that gets activated whenever a user `clicks` on the container for any of your `divs`. Keep in mind, you can use whatever handler you'd like, this is simply for demonstration sake.

We can use a **ternary operator** to perform actions if value of `yourTurn` is `true` or `false`. A basic **if/else** would work just as well.

Lets set up a basic example:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="move">Click Here to Simulate a Move</div> <!-- This is just a container for your TicTacToe game lets say -->
<div id="whosTurn">Your Turn!</div><!-- This is simply to show you the current state of turns -->
```

**jQuery / Javascript:**

```
$(function(){

    // Set up a base yourTurn variable without a value for now, just letting know javascript it exists.
    var yourTurn,
    // This is just for display purposes to show you who's turn it is.
        turnInfo = $('#whosTurn');

    // This function is the basic handler for changing turns. For now, we'll just do it whenever the user clicks on the box.
    $('#move').on('click', function(){
        changeTurns();
    });

    // This is the magic function which will always change turn on click. You would call this function whenever you've ensured that the user or computer have made a move.
    function changeTurns(){
        // This portion is only for visibility sake. The only real thing you need to modify the turn is the other line.
        yourTurn ? turnInfo.text('Your Turn!') : turnInfo.text('Computer Turn!')
        // This actually changes the yourTurn from true to false and vice-versa
        yourTurn = !yourTurn;
    }

});
```

You can see a working example here to work off of: http://jsfiddle.net/bqo1vj9d/1/

I see this as the easiest method to be able to simply tell if:

> (`yourTurn` = `true`) Its your turn
>     (`yourTurn` = `false`) Its the computer's turn

Comment: I like that a lot Nicholas, thank you. I hope you don't mind if I incorporate that into my app, but I'm afraid it doesn't solve the issue of the rest of my code not firing.

Comment: Simple. Don't move the computer on `if moveCount === 1`. Use it when `if yourTurn === false` :)

Comment: You can just fire `changeTurns()` during your events, as well as the computers events, to keep track of whos turn it is.

Comment: thanks for the effort man, but it still seems to stop after the x is appended.

Comment: Fun little Tic Tac Toe game I made as well. Unfortunately the computer's moves are entirely random at the moment, but still a fun way to look at it. http://jsfiddle.net/9kzeq/5/

Answer (score 0):

I modified your script and html to this... let me know if u need

**HTML**

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 box" id="top-left" data-box-number="1"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 box" id="top-middle" data-box-number="2"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 box" id="top-right" data-box-number="3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 box" id="middle-left" data-box-number="4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 box" id="middle-middle" data-box-number="5"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 box" id="middle-right" data-box-number="6"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 box" id="bottom-left" data-box-number="7"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 box" id="bottom-middle" data-box-number="8"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 box" id="bottom-right" data-box-number="9"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var playerName = prompt("Welcome to my world.  Enter your name so we can start");

alert("Welcome to the Game" + playerName + "!  Pick whatever square you'd like!");

var moveCount = 0,
 userArray = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 cpuArray = [0,0,0,0],
 topLeft = 0,
 topMiddle = 0,
 topRight = 0,
 middleLeft = 0,
 middleMiddle = 0,
 middleRight = 0,
 bottomLeft = 0,
 bottomMiddle = 0,
 bottomRight = 0;


//bind all the boxes together. You can use switch statement using boxnumber;
$(".box").bind("click", function () {
    var boxnumber = $(this).data("box-number");
    userMove($(this),boxnumber);
    computerMove(); // this will automaticatlly execute computers move after user's move
});


//user moves here
var userMove = function(dom,position){
    console.info("User moved.");
    $('<p>X</p>').appendTo(dom);
    // moveCount++; you can avoid this. 
    topLeft++;
    userArray[0] = position;
}    


//computer turn
var computerMove = function (){
    console.info("Computer moved.");
    alert("The computer cannot be defeated.  Click to see his turn.");
    if (topLeft === 1 || topRight === 1 || bottomRight === 1 || bottomLeft === 1) {
        $('<p>0</p>').appendTo("#middle-middle");
        //moveCount++;
        middleMiddle++;
        cpuArray[0] = 5;
    };

    if (topMiddle === 1 || middleLeft === 1 || middleRight === 1 || bottomMiddle === 1) {};
    if (middleMiddle === 1) { };

}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch Harry!  I'd love to use it but I just don't understand too much of it.  Maybe it's just too late at night.  I'll have to check it out again in the morning.  Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: Sure. let me know if u ve a problem with understanding tomorrow morning.